# How can I serve requests concurrently with Rails 4?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, concurrency, puma

I'm trying to serve multiple requests concurrently in Rails 4, something I was able to do very easily with `config.threadsafe!` and `Puma` in Rails 3.

Say I have this controller

```
class ConcurrentController < ApplicationController
  def index
    sleep 10000
  end

  def show
  end
end
```

I used to be able to just start puma with `puma -t 2:16 -p 3000` (for min 2 threads) and hit `index` and then `show` and still have `show` render properly.

In Rails 4, if I attempt to do the same thing Puma now locks on the `index` request and `show` never gets rendered. When I hit `Ctrl-C` for the server Puma gives me this error:

```
Rack app error: #<ThreadError: Attempt to unlock a mutex which is locked by another thread>
```

What am I missing here to get concurrency to work with Rails 4? `config.threadsafe!` is supposed to not be needed (and doesn't make a difference even if I try)

Comment: Have you tried running this with the production environment?

Comment: There should be no difference with Rails 4. Indeed Rails 4 is multithreaded by default. There must be something else in your environment/configuration that is causing the difference. How are you starting puma? With that command at the command line? Anything else relevant you can share from your development.rb file?

Comment: @fredrik - Please review my answer. I took the time to explain the option that allows concurrency and provided some references.
Unfortunately, although your answer can lead to a practical solution, it is not entirely correct.

Comment: I use rails 5.0.3 with `config.cache_classes = false` in `config/environments/development.rb` by default, but don't get this problem.

Comment: Try using multiple workers instead of just multiple threads, with `-w 2`. That will spin up two instances of the app to handle requests.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

I invite you to read about the configuration options of `config.threadsafe!` in this article [Removing config.threadsafe!](http://tenderlovemaking.com/2012/06/18/removing-config-threadsafe.html)
It will help you to understand better the options of `config.threadsafe!`, in particular to allow concurrency.

In Rails 4 `config.threadsafe!` is set by default.

---

### Now to the answer

In Rails 4 requests are wrapped around a Mutex by the Rack::Lock middleware in DEV environments by default.

If you want to **enable concurrency** you can set **`config.allow_concurrency=true`**. This will disable the Rack::Lock middleware. I would not delete it as mentioned in another answer to your question; that looks like a hack to me.

> **Note**: If you have `config.cache_classes=true` then an assignment to `config.allow_concurrency` (Rack::Lock request mutex) won't take
>   effect, concurrent requests are allowed by default. If you have
>   `config.cache_classes=false`, then you can set
>   `config.allow_concurrency` to either `true` or `false`. In DEV
>   environment you would want to have it like this
>
> ```
> config.cache_classes=false
> config.allow_concurrency=true
> ```
>
> The statement: *Which means that if config.cache_classes = false
>   (which it is by default in dev env) we can't have concurrent
>   requests.* is not correct.

### Appendix

You can refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30097643/1566187), which sets up an experiment testing concurrency using MRI and JRuby. The results are surprising. MRI was faster than JRuby.

The experiment with MRI concurrency is [on GitHub](https://github.com/Elyasin/limitedBandwidthMRI).
The experiment only tests concurrent request. There are no race conditions in the controller. However, I think it is not too difficult to implement example from the article above to test race conditions in a controller.

Comment: This seems correct and I will mark it as the correct answer, although I haven't taken the time to test it. I will note though, that config.allow_concurrency is a wholly undocumented feature[\[1\]](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v4.2.0/configuring.html#rails-general-configuration). It appears in the documentation for Rails 3[\[2\]](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v3.2.21/configuring.html#rails-general-configuration), but not for Rails 4.

Comment: Yes, that's right. We are left with not much documentation about the future use of that configuration option. Also, I just remembered, consider to set the connection pool of your database connection to the same size as the maximum number of threads. In your case 16.

Answer (score 23):

It seems that by default, in Rails 4, concurrent requests are not enabled in the Development environment.

I found this quote in the [documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#configuring-middleware).

> Rack::Lock wraps the app in mutex so it can only be called by a single thread at a time. Only enabled when config.cache_classes is false.

Which means that if `config.cache_classes = false` (which it is by default in dev env) we can't have concurrent requests.

Concurrent requests do work with my example in production environment.

One solution is to set `config.cache_classes = true` in the development environment, but then the code doesn't reload on a change, which doesn't really work for development.

The second kind of hacky solution is to disable the `Rack::Lock` middleware in development.

So if you were to add in `development.rb` the following line:

```
config.middleware.delete Rack::Lock
```

you should be able to have concurrent requests in development environment *with* cache classes disabled.

Comment: Where you using MRI Ruby or JRuby?  I was under the impression that multi-threaded didn't work in an example like this with MRI Ruby.

Comment: I can see with Puma there is a clustered mode (to specify workers) : https://github.com/puma/puma#clustered-mode but I can't get this example working (with a "sleep")

Comment: What are the drawbacks of deleting this middleware @Fredrik?

Comment: @JoãoPauloMotta Please see my answer. I proved a link to a blog post that discusses your question. The drawback is that you have to take care of race conditions within your controllers.

Comment: Delete Rack::Lock didn't work for me well. It loads the page, but it gives me timeout to connect database: "ActiveRecord::ConnectionNotEstablished (ActiveRecord::ConnectionNotEstablished):"

Comment: @AndreFigueiredo are you sure you've configured your database connection pool to have as many threads as you are trying to run in your app?

Comment: Yes, I'ts configured right. Without `Delete Rack:Lock` it works, With, it fails. Even static resources, fail to load.

Answer (score -1):

you can try unicorn this is very simple in development mode:

http://dave.is/unicorn.html