# ROR: Puma webserver doesn't process multiple request at a time

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, multithreading, webserver, puma

I'm using rails5.2. For testing i've created below controller.

```
class IndexController < ApplicationController
    def index        
        sleep(10)
        render text: "done"
    end
end
```

If I make 5 parallel requests, 1st request takes 10s, 2nd takes 20s, 3rd takes 30s and so on..

```
myAppRails5 aravind$ bin/rails server
=> Booting Puma
=> Rails 5.2.0 application starting in development 
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
Puma starting in single mode...
* Version 3.11.4 (ruby 2.5.1-p57), codename: Love Song
* Min threads: 5, max threads: 5
* Environment: development
* Listening on tcp://0.0.0.0:3000
Use Ctrl-C to stop
```

[Puma configuration](https://github.com/puma/puma) : Min threads: 5, max threads: 5
Rails 5.2.0 application starting in development

[development.rb](https://justpaste.it/6z4ue)

[puma.rb](https://justpaste.it/5gk04)

As per puma doc, threaded is supported. How do I achieve multi threading here?

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30228125/4160532), check if you have made all the necessary configuration changes.

Comment: You should post the the full log of when the server is starting, from Booting Puma to the list of workers. Also, try calling lsof -i :3000 to check how many processes are started

Comment: @Oxynum - Updated question for full log. lsof response which making multiple calls at https://justpaste.it/6r7ma

Comment: What operating system are you using? I'm not seeing this behavior on OS X 10.13.6 with puma.

Comment: @MikeGorski OS X 10.12.6